# How to patch haproxy for OpenSSL vulnerability USN-2830-1

Tags: openssl, known-vulnerabilities, ubuntu

This is regular security task, I have a number for servers running HAproxy on ubuntu 14.04 LTC on AWS. Since USN-2830-1 is a OpenSSL vulnerability I believe we must patch our HAproxy instances, but on the official docs of ubuntu, it just says :

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

I am not very sure if this is sufficient or not. Any guidance is appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Per the [Ubuntu vulnerability](http://www.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-2830-1/), running those commands is sufficient. Ubuntu is a reliable Linux distro, not known to make false claims. So you should be secure.

Comment: +1. As long as it is the repositories in /etc/apt/source.list. Which unless they have been specifically changed, will be.